# Calling web3.utils.BN.add gives error: Cannot create property 'negative' on number

Tags: ethereum, web3js, truffle, bignumber.js

At truffle test, I am trying to add two Big Numbers together using the following code:

```
myBignumber = new web3.utils.BN(1);
myBignumber.add(2)
```

But it caused this error:

> Cannot create property 'negative' on number 2

Versions:

- Truffle 5.0
- Web3 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BN used at Web3 has some open issues ([ref](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/2171))

**Suggested Alternative:**

Try using another BigNumber library that has a working addition function ([like this](http://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/#plus)).

To use the library install it:

```
npm install bignumber.js
```

Now at your truffle test:

```
    var BigNumber = require("bignumber.js");

    ...
    // Instead of the commented lines, use the next, uncommitted, ones:
    // myBignumber = new web3.utils.BN(1);
    // myBignumber.add(2)
    myBignumber = new BigNumber(1); 
    myBignumber.plus(2);
```

Comment: Thanks, using bignumber.js solved this issue for me. However, the correct call should be `myBignumber = new BigNumber(1); myBignumber.plus(2)`;

Comment: Thanks @MartenS, I forgot to put the working code snippet. I updated the answer now.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can also instantiate the number 2 as a big number to resolve the error:

```
myBignumber = new web3.utils.BN(1);
myBignumber.add(new web3.utils.BN(2));
```

This way you don't have to install another BigNumber library.

Answer (score 1):

If you with to add a Javascript native `Number` to a `BN`,
use `.addn()`:

```js
const myBignumber = new web3.utils.BN(1);
myBignumber.addn(2);
// BN { negative: 0, words: [ 3 ], length: 1, red: null }
myBignumber.addn(2).toString();
// '3'
```

If you wish to add one `BN` to another `BN`,
use `.add()`:

```js
const myBignumber = new web3.utils.BN(1);
myBignumber.add(new web3.utils.BN(2));
// BN { negative: 0, words: [ 3 ], length: 1, red: null }
myBignumber.add(new BN(2)).toString();
// '3'
```